# PowerBI how to get first value from other column

Tags: powerbi

In PowerBI I have this table:

| Date | Activities | Status | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | null | ABC |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | null | null |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | null | null |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | null | null |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | Succes | null |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | null | DEF |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | null | null |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | null | null |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | null | null |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | Failed | null |

As result I want this:

| Date | Activities | Status | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | Succes | ABC |
| 2022-11-16 | Not important | Failed | DEF |

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Power Query Editor:

[image]

1. Select [Customer], then Transform - Fill down
2. Select [Status], then Filter (dropdown) - Remove Empty

[image]